# How to solve "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with the SwipeView in my Xamarin forms app.

I have a SwipeView inside a CollectionView. The CollectionView is inside a StackLayout which is inside a ScrollView which is inside a Stacklayout.

```
   <ScrollView Margin="10,5,10,5" x:Name="MyViewList">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame BorderColor="Teal">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="Deine Vokabel" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Teal"/>
                            <CollectionView x:Name="VList">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <SwipeView>
                                            <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                                <SwipeItems>
                                                    <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="LightPink"/>
                                                    <SwipeItem Text="Edit" BackgroundColor="LightGreen"/>
                                                </SwipeItems>
                                            </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition 
                                                        Width="*"
                                                    />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition 
                                                        Height="*"
                                                    />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Teal" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Number:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="MYText:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="MyText:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="MyText1:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="MyText2:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="MyText:" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                                <Label Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                                                <BoxView Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Teal" HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </SwipeView>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

If I run my app on Android (iOS not tested so far) I get this error:

> 07-09 15:45:28.131 D/Mono    (28233): Requesting loading reference 4
> (of 6) of
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll
> 07-09 15:45:28.132 D/Mono    (28233): Loading reference 4 of
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp/files/.**override**/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll
> asmctx DEFAULT, looking for Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null 07-09
> 15:45:28.132 D/Mono    (28233): Assembly Ref addref
> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView[0x7a3866a480] ->
> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView[0x7a47e79a80]: 2
> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

This is a screenshot of debug breaking:

[image]

I use Xamarin.Forms 4.7 and VisualStudio 2019.

What I'm missing? Something in the Resources? Is the SwipeView not working in a ScrollView?

Comment: first, you need to look at the InnerException property to figure out what the root cause is

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: use the debugger to examine the exception object

Comment: I know how to debug, but I don't come or get the inner exception of this. The code behind is working fine, only the visualization is not working

Comment: you are getting an exception that should include an Exception object.  That object has an InnerException property that will include details of the root cause

Comment: I edit my question with a screenshot of the exception, there is no object.

Comment: use a global exception handler to capture it, or try using appcenter.ms

Comment: ok I will try it and come back

Comment: I have tried a global exception handling, but it does'nt gave me any output... There must be something wrong in the ScrollView and SwipView hirachy, because if I exclude the SwipeView, everything is working fine

Comment: Update the package in Nuget to the latest version .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have updated, but it is still not working, the same error occurres again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have added the flag for the swipeview, given that it is still experimental. The code snippet lays within the App.xaml.cs file for the Xamarin Forms shared project.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {           
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "CollectionView_Experimental", "SwipeView_Experimental" });
        }
   }
```

Comment: No problem.  Careful with the SwipeView if you update to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.1179. If one of the child view elements within your SwipeView uses a GestureRecognizer, i.e. TapGestureRecognizer, the SwipeView will not slide to expose the underlying SwipeItems.  A task for this issue, on Android, is currently in Review

Answer (score 0):

Remove FastRenderers_Experimental in MainActivity.
or, move the FastRenderers_Experimental to the last.

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("SwipeView_Experimental");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");
```

instead of

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("SwipeView_Experimental");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```